# MySQL - query to get all rows that a specific character is non-English

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table that has `nvarchar` elements.
This table has two kinds of elements:

1. elements with only digit characters
2. elements with digit characters and the 3rd character is non-English character

I want a query to get all rows that their 3rd character is non-English.

**EDIT**

use  `WHERE SUBSTRING(<table>.ColumnName, 3, 1) NOT BETWEEN '0' AND '9'` worked for me either

Comment: But any object which is 1st kind is also a 2nd kind. (digit is non-English character). Do you want them to be in output?

Comment: I meant that they are not digit and not English. @CrafterKolyan

Comment: So actually you want to have query that has 3rd character as non-digit non-English character?

Comment: Define non-English character??

Comment: I want a query to get all rows  that their 3rd character is not digit, and I can't use something like ( LIKE [a-z] ) because it's not English.@CrafterKolyan

Comment: Use something like `... WHERE 
 SUBSTRING(<table>.ColumnName, 3, 1) NOT BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z' 
 AND
 SUBSTRING(<table>.ColumnName, 3, 1) NOT BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'`

Comment: Persian character.@RaymondNijland

Comment: Oh not English then you need to use `NOT BETWEEN` instead

Comment: The character is not English.And I tried this but didn't work. SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 3, 1) NOT LIKE '[0-9]' @RaymondNijland

Comment: Where do you see iam using `NOT LIKE`?

Comment: I used NOT LIKE before I post this question. but with NOT BETWEEN '0' AND '9' it worked. Thank you so much :) @RaymondNijland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `regexp_like` with a regex that the third character isn't a digit:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(mycol, '..[^[:digit:]].*')
```

In MySQL versions older than 8.0, you could use the `regexp` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  mycol REGEXP '..[^[:digit:]].*'
```

Comment: @saba care to share some details?

Comment: @saba I meant sharing details about "it didn't work".

Comment: @saba you still haven't explained why this query doesn't work. Are you getting an error? If so, please share it. Are you getting the wrong results? If so, please share some sample data, the result you're getting and explain how its wrong.

Comment: @saba That mean that you're using a MySQL version that's older than 8.0. I've edited my answer with an alternative syntax that should work on older versions too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RLIKE operator, below is the query for matching the third character which is not a digit and not an English alphabet

```
SELECT * FROM 
mytable 
where SUBSTR(mycol,3,1) NOT RLIKE '^[A-Za-z0-9]$';
```